# Angular Material 12 Mat-Spinner color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I want to dynamically change the color of mat-spinner in my typescript code. For some reason my code is not working anymore. The code below shows how it was working. I need help.

```js
spinnerStyle() {
    return { stroke: mycustomcolor };
}
```

```html
 <mat-progress-spinner
      diameter="30"
      mode="determinate"
      strokeWidth="7"
      [ngStyle]="spinnerStyle()"
    >
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling the Spinner stroke from the root works. Its a bit hacky but easy.

```css
::ng-deep mat-progress-spinner.spinner-color > svg > circle {
  stroke: unset !important;
}
```

```html
<mat-progress-spinner
      diameter="30"
      mode="determinate"
      [ngStyle]="spinnerStyle()"
      class="spinner-color"
    >
</mat-progress-spinner>
```

Answer (score 0):

The API for the progress spinner has a color input that takes a ThemePalette, not a color. [See example here](https://v12.material.angular.io/components/progress-spinner/examples#progress-spinner-configurable).

You must add a material palette for the color you want the spinner to change. [Theming docs are here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming).

Also, you should never call a method from the template directly unless your component change detection strategy is `onPush`.

Comment: I dont want to be limited to 3 colors. Creating multiple ThemePalette´s is not the way to go.

Comment: You can create as many palettes are you want. If you want to control the color of the spinner directly, use a different spinner.